# What's the difference between draw closer and get closer?

Tags: difference

> “The two of them walked toward the road and the stone marker. Behind them, other cars were pulling out. A woman began screaming abruptly. Unconsciously, Garraty and McVries **drew closer** together. Neither of them looked back. Ahead of them was the road, wide and black.” ———Excerpt From the Long Walk

In the above sentence, if I were to replace **drew closer** with **got closer**, would the meaning change? In other words, does draw closer convey something different from just physically get closer?

Answer (score 2):

There's a descriptive difference. One of the uses of the verb **draw** is to mean **pull** eg "She drew her coat tightly around her shoulders," to take an example sentence from [this dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/draw). A lot of the other uses of the verb **draw** still carry this connotation that something is being pulled, sometimes as a metaphor. Like if you **draw attention**, it sounds like you're pulling the attention of other people towards yourself.

In the extract you're asking about, it's correct to think **drew closer together** has the same definition as **got closer together**. Comprehensively, they both describe the same thing happening. But with **drew closer together**, it also conveys this feeling that the two characters are being pulled towards each other (as if they naturally want to move closer together). That nuance would be lost if you replaced **drew** with **got**.

Comment: Yes. It says _unconsciously_ they drew together. It was _involuntary_. You can't unconsciously _get_ together.

Comment: @Old Brixtonian, so, get closer is more of a voluntary action/conscious choice, right?

Comment: @Ray Yes. "Drew" fits better with "unconsciously". Did you ever do that English exercise where you have to replace each occurrence of the word "nice" with a better or stronger adjective? Another exercise might ask you to replace the words **get** and **got**, which are often useful but can be bland and colourless. "It _got_ warmer"..."It _grew_ warmer". "They'll _get to be_ friends"..."They'll _became_ friends"..."_got closer_"..."_drew_ closer" etc.

Comment: 'Get' is also rather informal and casual compared with 'draw'.